How to generate a multi-page PDF with mixed orientations (vertical and horizontal) from an HTML document?
I have an HTML document where each section represents a single A4 page. I’d like some sections to be in portrait (vertical) orientation and others in landscape (horizontal).
However, when I generate a PDF (using chrome), it creates one large page that’s the height of A4 (portrait) and the width of A4 (landscape), rather than separate pages with mixed orientations.
Is there a way to achieve this so that each section outputs as its own A4 page with the specified orientation?
Thank you!

Have you looked at paged.js?

Will check it out, thanks!

Printing a PDF with mixed orientations is not possible with just chrome.
The closest you can get would be to print one page rotated 90 degrees and then rotate the page manually in a PDF editor.

Alright, thanks, I appreciate the information
